# Sound comes through speakers AND headphones on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I have an HP Pavilion Dv6-2157wm laptop with Altec Lansing speakers, SRS Premium Sound, powered by an IDT card I believe.  Well, when I plug in my headphones (or earbuds) sound comes through them but also from the main speakers as well.  I don't believe it is a hardware issue because the jack works fine on Windows and no sound comes from the speakers.  Also, did I mention that I'm dual-booting?  I've looked all around, but I can't seem to find a driver for ANY of these services.  Oh, and I've also tried the GNOME Alsa Mixer (from the Ubuntu Software Center) and it didn't yield much.  What do you guys suggest?  Please help!  I really like what I see in Ubuntu and have even considered making it my mainstream OS.

P.S. If I have to try anything via the Terminal, could you please walk me through it?  I know only the basics of the terminal and have turned to the software center for my installations.

Comment: What about using pavucontrol to switch Output Devices >> Port to Headphones. That seems to have done the trick for me on Debian/sid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried controlling this with PulseAudio pavucontrol? On the Configuration tab you should have something like Analogue Stereo Duplex, on the Output Devices tab you can select the port for this built-in audio device, either Speakers or Headphones and when your music player is running you should see your player listed on the Playback tab where you can control the output volume.

Comment: Yes, I have tinkered around with it, but to no avail.  I accessed the alsamixer via the terminal and via a downloaded application in search of the "Auto-Mute function", but it yielded no results.